# Carrierwave slow upload/saves using :fog or :s3 on an EC2 instance

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, carrierwave

I followed Ryan Bates railscasts and all uploads are very slow in any config I use (:fog, :s3).

I am on an EC2 medium instance and using s3 in the same region. According to the logs, transfers from ec2 to s3 are fast. However, any other upload to the instance works at normal speed (I also upload zip files for other purposes).

It's really when using carrierwave that the slowness appears. If I save a user without avatar photo, it also saves fast.  As soon as I upload an image (40k or 400k), it takes about 6/7 seconds to save/update and generate 2 smaller versions thumbnails. I also tried to remove thumb creation, same thing (6/7 seconds)
(Rails 3.1.10, mongoid 3.0, carrierwave 0.5.8, fog 1.3.1)

Any clue what can be happening here? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have you tested this with newer versions of carrierwave & fog? Yours are 18+ months old. Past that, since this doesn't seem to be happening to lots of other people, it's probably something specific to your app or server configuration. It could be worth adding some logged benchmarks to your carrierwave gem, to see exactly which step is taking so long. I'd check [CarrierWave::Fog::Storage](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb) first.